# Get Expiration date without Whois

Tags: python, sockets, whois

I was wondering how would you be able to get an expiration date of a domain name without using whois? I been looking into this for awhile but I still haven't been able to figure out a way around it.

Comment: **expiration date of a website** a website does not expire, an ssl certificate does.

Comment: Building `poach_domain.py` ?

Comment: A domain does expire and you need to pay to renew it.

Comment: No, there is no central repository for this.  "whois" knows how to query the major domain hosts.  That's where the information lives.

Answer (score 0):

The informantion you are looking is stored in the registry operator the domain is registered. To get the information you have two options either whois or the replacment of whois that is icann lookup. You can search information about a domain [here](https://lookup.icann.org/) and also more informations about the icann lookup.